# Why do these kind of $f(n)$'s make the limsup statement hold?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $g(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Is it true that $g \in \{f \ | \ \limsup A_{f(n)} \subseteq \limsup A_n\}$ for some sequence $A_n$?

Suppose g does not approach $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ where $K < \infty$.

Is it true that $g \notin \{f \ | \ \limsup A_{f(n)} \subseteq \limsup A_n\}$ for some sequence $A_n$?

The sequence $(A_n)$ doesn't satisfy any particular property, apart from $\limsup A_n$ existing which always exists [(I think?)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Sequences_of_sets).

Comment: Are you sure you mean $g \to K$?  This would mean $g(n) = K$ for all $n > n_0$, making the question rather obvious.

Comment: @ErickWong I am not sure. It is supposed to be the negation of "g(n)→∞ as n→∞." How do I negate that then?

Comment: Write out the definition of $g(n)\to\infty$ and negate it.  Or just say $g(n)\not\to\infty$.  This doesn't mean $g$ has to converge to anything, nor even does $g$ need to be bounded.

Comment: You need to give a quantifier for $A_n$ in your question.  is your RHS the set of all $f$ that satisfy the $\subseteq$ for _every_ choice of $A_n$ or for _some_ choice of $A_n$?

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On your first question:

Fix some element $x\notin\limsup A_{n}$, wich means:

$$\text{some }n_{x}\in\mathbb{N}\text{ exists with: }\forall k>n_{x}\left[x\notin A_{k}\right]$$

From $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g\left(n\right)=\infty$ it follows:
 $$\text{some }m_{x}\in\mathbb{N}\text{ exists with: }\forall k>m_{x}\left[g\left(k\right)>n_{x}\right]$$
and consequently: $$\forall k>m_{x}\left[x\notin A_{g\left(k\right)}\right]$$

The last statement tells us that $x\notin\limsup A_{g\left(n\right)}$.

Proved is now that $\limsup A_{g\left(n\right)}\subseteq\limsup A_{n}$
if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g\left(n\right)=\infty$ .

---

On your second question.

No, not in general. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1294044/75923) for a proof that counterexamples can easily be constructed.

If e.g. $A_{n}=A$ for each $n$ then $\limsup A_{g\left(n\right)}=\limsup A_{n}$
is true for any function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks drhab. As for the second question. so this is wrong? "Necessary and sufficient condition: f(n)→∞ when n→∞." http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928535/what-kind-of-fns-make-the-limsup-statement-is-true-what-kind-dont#comment1945190_928535

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. It is sufficient but in general not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my question may have been wrong. How about now?

Comment: If $g\left(n\right)\rightarrow\infty$ then $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_{g\left(n\right)}\subseteq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_{g\left(n\right)}$
for every sequence $\left\{ A_{n}\right\} $. If $g\left(n\right)\rightarrow\infty$
is not true then there are sequences $\left\{ A_{n}\right\} $ such
that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_{g\left(n\right)}\subseteq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_{g\left(n\right)}$ 
but also there can be sequences $\left\{ A_{n}\right\} $
s.t. $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_{g\left(n\right)}\subseteq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_{g\left(n\right)}$
is not true.

Comment: Btw, if a question is posted then it is not okay to change it essentially later. That is not neat towards persons who have answered. You (could) make their answers irrelevant.